# Using for loop function in ggstratsplot in r

Tags: r, loops

I have a csv-file with round about 180 columns (in my example called `df`). So far I managed to use the `ggstatsplot::ggbetweenstats` package to plot the data. One column called `Group` contains the information of the treatment condition and represents the **x-axis**. The **y-axis** is changing for each plot. (in the example below it's `Bcells.CD45`)

```r
ggstatsplot::ggbetweenstats (df, x = Group, y = Bcells.CD45 , plot.type = "violin")
```

Now, I tried to use the `for` loop function to replace the value of the y-axis for each generated plot.

```r
for (i in names(df) [1:ncol(df)]) { ggstatsplot::ggbetweenstats(df, x = Group, y = i , plot.type = "violin")}
```

R returns the following error:

> can't subset columns that don't exist.
>   x The column `i` doesn't exist.
>   Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.

I have the impression that either the **ggstatsplot** package cant't handle `i` as placeholder for changing column-names or I'm making a mistake in defining `i`.

Thanks for your help!

Best Martin

Answer (score 1):

Please have a look at the FAQ-vignette on `ggstatsplot` website, which documents how to use `ggstatsplot` functions in a `for` loop:
https://indrajeetpatil.github.io/ggstatsplot/articles/web_only/faq.html

Relevant text:

[image]

Comment: i have a similar question where i want to plot the coefficient of multiple models I would be glad if you give some suggestion or help